# Camera game 2d Javascript using box2d

Tags: javascript

I'm cloningg, i'm doing camera 2d in angry bird game using javascript html5 game and box2d.js .
I'm using context.translate(x,y) to move canvas, but i meet an error like this : many image
of birds saved

http://i1168.photobucket.com/albums/r489/thegioisach1/1.png

Everyone has a solution about camera 2d??
Thanks!!!

Comment: I'm not familiar with HTML5, but it seems like you need to clear the canvas between each frame.

Comment: So, how to clear canvas betwwen each frame? context.clearrect(..)??? i use it but not .

Comment: See the first part of my response. I'm not familiar with HTML5. You could try searching for it.

Comment: Anybody help me:(

Answer (score 3):

#### Short answer:

Call `context.clearRect( 0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height )` just before drawing onto the canvas every frame.

---

It's not really about the camera though, unless it's responsible for the drawing onto the canvas. It's also not about box2d.

As mentioned by Byte56, you need to clear the canvas before drawing. This is because the methods used to draw onto the canvas (e.g. `context.drawImage`) only draws on top of the existing image.

The canvas can't clear the frame automatically because the canvas would not know when to clear it. Luckily, the canvas allows the following methods to clear it manually.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142535/how-to-clear-the-canvas-for-redrawing suggested two ways (by Pentium10):

1. `context.clearRect( x, y, w, h )` where x and y is usually zero, or wherever you want it to start clearing (the top-left corner), and w and h are width and height respectively.
2. `canvas.width = canvas.width` or if that doesn't work try `canvas.width = someOtherWidth;` and *then* setting it back `canvas.width = width`. (**note:** Prestaul noted that using `clearRect` can be 10% faster than changing the width)

Later Prestaul reminded that if you had modified the transformation, you'll need to save the current transformation, then use `clearRect`, and finally changing back the transformation.

trembl also reminded that you need to `beginPath()` in order for lines to be cleared.

Please **go over to that page** yourself, because I did not cover everything mentioned there. That page can also be found by googling "javascript canvas clear". Also, remember that even though it may work on your web browser, doesn't mean that it will work on others!

Anyways, good luck on your game!